# R - Reduce function used for merging returns a list instead of a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge, reduce

I'm trying to merge multiple dataframes according to their names.

My dataframes are named 
Cluster_1_N1, Cluster_1_N2, Cluster_1_N3 
Cluster_2_N1, Cluster_2_N2, Cluster_2_N3 
etc with 3, 4 ... They all contain two columns.

```
> Cluster_1_N1
ID   counts_N1
1       405
2         6
3       201
4        40

> Cluster_1_N2
ID   counts_N2
1       657
2         9
3       250
4        77
```

The merge will be done on "ID" column. I want to obtain multiple dataframes, named "Cluster_1", "Cluster_2"... structured like this

```
>Cluster_1
ID counts_N1 counts_N2    counts_N3
1       405         657    10
2         6         9      50
3       201        250     55
4        40         77     68

>Cluster_2
ID counts_N1 counts_N2  counts_N3
1      1        652        11
2      7         3         52
3      58        2         56
4      46        7         68
```

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:2) {
z <- paste ("C", i, sep = "")
n <- paste("Cluster_", i, sep = "")

assign (n, Reduce(function(...) merge (..., by="ID", all= T)),
              list(mget(ls(pattern=z)))))
                                          }
```

This code returns me "Cluster_1" and "Cluster_2" objects, but these objects are lists (containing the appropriate dataframes to merge together) but not dataframes! Thus, the Reduce function lists correctly all the "cluster_1" and "cluster_2" dataframes I want to merge, but does not merge them...

Where is my mistake? 
(I hope I'm clear enough, this is my first post ever... )

Comment: You initially provide `Cluster_1_N1`, but your `mget` is looking for `C1`. What if you use `z <- sprintf("Cluster_%s_*", i)`? BTW: Dealing with identically-structured dataframes like this can easily be cumbersome, I urge you to consider dealing with [lists of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207).

Comment: Just to understand this better, is this part of a function in which you won't know the names of the data frames, hence using `mget`? It also looks like you're calling `Reduce` on each individual data frame, not on a list of them, since you're doing the `Reduce` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way in base `R`:

```
pattern  <- "Cluster_(\\d+)_N\\d+"
dfs_all  <- mget(ls(pattern=pattern))
df_split <- split(dfs_all,gsub(pattern, "\\1", names(dfs_all))) 
lapply(df_split, Reduce, f = merge)

# $`1`
#   ID counts_N1 counts_N2
# 1  1       405       657
# 2  2         6         9
# 3  3       201       250
# 4  4        40        77
# 
# $`2`
#   ID counts_N1 counts_N2
# 1  1         1       652
# 2  2         7         3
# 3  3        58         2
# 4  4        46         7
```

I would recommend however that you fix the code upstream if you're the one responsible for getting the data in this shape, it's much cleaner to work with lists from the start.

**data**

```
Cluster_1_N1 <-read.table(text=
                            "ID   counts_N1
                          1       405
                          2         6
                          3       201
                          4        40",h=T,strin=F)

Cluster_1_N2 <-read.table(text=
                            "ID   counts_N2
                          1       657
                          2         9
                          3       250
                          4        77",h=T,strin=F)

Cluster_2_N1 <-read.table(text=
                            "ID   counts_N1
                          1         1
                          2         7
                          3        58
                          4        46",h=T,strin=F)

Cluster_2_N2 <-read.table(text=
                            "ID   counts_N2
                          1       652
                          2         3
                          3         2
                          4         7",h=T,strin=F)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Another little question though: as my dataframes do not have the same number of rows, how can I specify the "all = True" merge parameter in the code you proposed?

Comment: You're welcome, try to replace `f= merge` by `f = function(x,y) merge(x,y, all = TRUE)`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!!